# Rails: Pass association object to the View

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Model `Item` belongs_to `User`.

In my controller I have code like this:

```
@items = Item.find(:all)
```

I need to have a corresponding User models for each item in my View templates.

it works in controller(but not in View template):

```
@items.each { |item| item.user }
```

But manual looping just to build associations for View template kinda smells.
How can I do this not in a creepy way?

Comment: i am not sure i understand what you mean but might Item.find(:all, :include => :user) solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the :include option for find:

```
@items = Item.find(:all, :include => :user)
```

Be sure to read the eager loading section under [associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) so you're not doing a bunch of database lookups when they can be combined.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like following.
Just example

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Item Name</td>
    <td>User Name</td>
  </tr>
<% for item @items %>
   <tr>
     <td><%= item.item_name %></td>
     <td><%= item.user.name %></td>
   </tr>
<% end %>
```

OR

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Item Name</td>
    <td>User Name</td>
  </tr>
<% @items.each { |item| %>
   <tr>
     <td><%= item.item_name %></td>
     <td><%= item.user.name %></td>
   </tr>
<% } %>
```